# WIX installer does not launch after upgrading Wix v3 to v4

Tags: wix, wix4

I have a .Net solution which have a WPF Project, **WIX Package** project and another **WIX Bundle** project. It was previously in Wix v3 and setup was working fine.

Now I have upgraded WIX v3 to v4 using WIX auto conversion. After the conversion, if I try to install newly compiled .msi file, it works fine. But the Bundle .exe doesn't even show UI. There are no events in Event Viewer too. What could be issue here?

Here's my Bundle.wxs file

```
<?ifndef Version?>
<?define Version = 1.1 ?>
<?endif?>
<?define InstallStatus=[WixBundleInstalled]?>
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal">

  <Bundle Name="MyApp" Version="$(var.Version)" Manufacturer="Me" UpgradeCode="97baf4b4-4e07-43bb-9042-123bf3e29f6e" IconSourceFile="Resources/kangaroo.ico">

    <bal:Condition Message="You’re using an unsupported version of Windows. App requires Windows 7 SP1 or later." Condition="((VersionNT &gt;= v5.1) AND (ServicePackLevel &gt;= 3)) OR ((VersionNT &gt;= v5.2) AND (ServicePackLevel &gt;= 2)) OR ((VersionNT &gt;= v6.1) AND (ServicePackLevel &gt;= 1)) OR (VersionNT &gt;= v6.2)" />
    
    <Variable Name="LaunchTarget" Value="[LocalAppDataFolder]\MyApp\MyApp.exe" Type="formatted" />

    <BootstrapperApplication>
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LogoFile="Resources/Sidebar.png" ThemeFile="Resources/ClassicTheme.xml" LocalizationFile="Resources/ClassicTheme.wxl" LicenseUrl="" Theme="hyperlinkSidebarLicense" />
    </BootstrapperApplication>

    <Chain DisableSystemRestore="yes">
      <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx462Redist" />
      <RollbackBoundary />
      
      <MsiPackage Id="SetupAdmin" Compressed="yes" SourceFile="$(var.MSIInstaller.TargetDir)MyApp.msi" Vital="yes">
        <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="[INSTALLDIR]" />
        <MsiProperty Name="BUNDLEKEY" Value="[WixBundleProviderKey]" />
      </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the log. It's almost certainly showing a problem loading your theme. There's no auto-converter for custom theme files.

Comment: There was nothing in the log. But you were right, it was issue with theme. I downloaded fresh theme & strings file from wix repo did the customizations again. Thanks for the help.